# Can someone help me predict a few numbers that follow the pattern in these numbers?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have these numbers:

9149
5915
9199
7147
6156
7917

There obviously is some sort of pattern between them in that the first and the last digits are the same, and the second and third digits alternate between 1 and one other number. 
Is there any pattern or algorithm that can help me generate other similar numbers?  Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Your question has nothing to do with [tag:analysis], please read the tag excerpt before applying a tag.
Also you should elaborate more on what your goal is. Do you want to find a sequence such that its first few members are the ones you just listed or do you want an algorithm (like a computer-routine) to generate random sequences with this structure?

Comment: Hello AlexR, thanks for getting back. Sorry about posting my question using the wrong tag. I would like to be able to generate more numbers that follow the rule (or rules) that the numbers I posted follow.

Answer (score 1):

Pseudocode in MATLAB-like notation:

```
function num = randomSpecialNumber(index)
    % is the 1 left or right?
    parity = mod(index, 2);
    % parity = 0: num = XY1X
    % parity = 1: num = X1YX
    x = randi(10)-1; % Select the leading and trailing digit, 0 to 9
    y = randi(10)-1; % Select the middle digit, 0 to 9
    if (parity == 0)
        num = 1001*x + 100*y + 10;
    else
        num = 1001*x + 100 + 10*y;
    end
end
```